# remove duplicate (non-unique) paired values

Tags: stata

I'm working with an edge list in Stata, of the type:

```
var1 var2
 a    1
 a    2
 a    3
 b    1
 b    2
 1    a
 2    b
```

I want to remove non-unique pairs such as 1a and 2b (which are same as a1 and b2 for me). How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
. clear 

. input str1 (var1 var2) 

          var1       var2
  1.  a    1
  2.  a    2
  3.  a    3
  4.  b    1
  5.  b    2
  6.  1    a
  7.  2    b
  8. end 

. gen first = cond(var1 <= var2, var1, var2) 

. gen second = cond(var1 <= var2, var2, var1) 

. list 

     +------------------------------+
     | var1   var2   first   second |
     |------------------------------|
  1. |    a      1       1        a |
  2. |    a      2       2        a |
  3. |    a      3       3        a |
  4. |    b      1       1        b |
  5. |    b      2       2        b |
     |------------------------------|
  6. |    1      a       1        a |
  7. |    2      b       2        b |
     +------------------------------+

. duplicates list first second 

Duplicates in terms of first second

  +--------------------------------+
  | group:   obs:   first   second |
  |--------------------------------|
  |      1      1       1        a |
  |      1      6       1        a |
  |      2      5       2        b |
  |      2      7       2        b |
  +--------------------------------+

. duplicates drop first second, force  

Duplicates in terms of first second

(2 observations deleted)

. list 

     +------------------------------+
     | var1   var2   first   second |
     |------------------------------|
  1. |    a      1       1        a |
  2. |    a      2       2        a |
  3. |    a      3       3        a |
  4. |    b      1       1        b |
  5. |    b      2       2        b |
     +------------------------------+
```

The easy part of the answer is to use `duplicates drop`. But how to get the data so that `1 a` and `a 1` are seen to be duplicates? This is all documented [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0043). We can sort the values in each observation so that (in this case) both sort to `1 a`.  The linked paper says much more, but that's the main idea, and `cond()` helps.

Comment: You can accept the answer to gain some reputation. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers